# Debugger is not entering into "If loop"

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUSa1.png) is not entering into "If loop". The debugger even enters into the for loop, it checks for the length and it also increments i.

```
function doesStevenLikeSpagetti (favoriteFoods) {
debugger;
  for (var i=0; i<favoriteFoods.length; i++ ) {
    if( favoriteFoods[i] === "spaghetti") {
      return true;
    }
  }
return false;
}
doesStevenLikeSpagetti("spaghetti");
```

Comment: as i seen favoriteFoods is not an array, is an string

Comment: `s !== spaghetti`, a simple `console.log(favoriteFoods[i])` before the if would have been enough to find the error for yourself

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - so what if it's a string? do you know javascript?

Comment: If `favouriteFoods` actually was an array, there's `Array.prototype.indexOf` to check whether it contains 'spaghetti'…

Comment: It seems like your function is expecting an array: `doesStevenLikeSpaghetti(["fish", "avocado", "spaghetti"]);`

Comment: What you want to acheive ?

Comment: @vsync if is an string never be the if and it must use charAt, Have you take a look to the gven print¿?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var favoriteFoods = "spaghetti";

for( var i=0; i<favoriteFoods.length; i++ ){
    console.log(favoriteFoods[i]);
    if( favoriteFoods[i] === "spaghetti")
       console.log("found: ", i)
}
```

Nothing will be found because the loop is iterating the letters themselves of the word in the variable `favoriteFoods`.

### But if you use an Array:

```js
var favoriteFoods = ["pasta", "spaghetti", "apple"];

for( var i = 0; i < favoriteFoods.length; i++ ){
  console.log(favoriteFoods[i]);
  if( favoriteFoods[i] == "spaghetti" )
    console.log("found: " + favoriteFoods[i] + " at index: ", i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing each character of the parameter *favoriteFoods* with the whole word (string) "spaghetti".

You should call your function like this, to pass an array and make the comparation with each of the elements of the array passed as parameter.

```
doesStevenLikeSpagetti(["spaghetti"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you try to loop a string, so `favoriteFoods[i]` will be `s` on the first iteration.

I suppose you have a list of things that your character likes, and want to check if he likes something. You can do that using `indexOf` (or `includes)`, there's no reason to loop at all.

```js
let stevenLikes = ["spaghetti", "pizza", "bacon"];

function doesStevenLike(food) {
 return stevenLikes.indexOf(food) > -1;
 // or ES6 includes 
 // return stevenLikes.includes(food);
}

console.log(doesStevenLike("spaghetti"));
console.log(doesStevenLike("chicken feed"));
console.log(doesStevenLike("bacon"));
```